# android.os.DeadObjectException Youtube Video with enabled ads

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am writing a sample program in which i am using Youtube API, and it works fine, but I noticed that application crashes every time I try to play a video with enabled ads.

**Log:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.DeadObjectException
at com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.a(SourceFile:516)
at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.jar.a.a.a(SourceFile:485)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.h.onTransact(SourceFile:413)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.d$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.s.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.b.a.aq.a(SourceFile:706)
at com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.a(SourceFile:513)
```

**few Questions:**

1. How can i resolve this issue ?
2. Is it possible to block the ad on Youtube Player API ?